# If $m+x=m$ for all integers $m$, then $x=0$

Tags: proof-verification, arithmetic, integers

I am learning proofs and, have the following statement:

> Let $x$ belong to the set of integers. If $x$ has the property that for each integer $m$, $m+x=m$, then $x=0$.

Here is my strategy:

\begin{align*}
m + x &= m \\
(m + x) &= (m) \\
(-m) + (m + x) &= (-m) + (m) \\
((-m) + m) + x &= 0 \\
(0) + x &= 0 \\
x &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

Would that be good? This would say that there is only one unique solution for any $m$ that belongs to $\mathbb Z$ and it's $0$.

Comment: If this is true for any integer $m$ then it holds for $m=0$. Thus we can say $0+x=0$ which means $x=0$.

Comment: Your argument is fine, however.

Comment: Your proof has the advantage that it proves that $x=0$ if the $m+x=m$ for *some* $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algebra is right, though at this level you might be expected to explain it better. But your conclusion could be misinterpreted: it is *not* enough to say that for any $m$ there is a unique solution (i.e. $x$), since this means that $x$ might depend on $m$. What is true is that if $x$ that satisfies the equation for each $m$, then $x=0$. Your words are not exactly the former, but they could be reasonably read in that way.

As Joel mentions, your proof is a bit longer than strictly necessary to solve this problem. But as Zubin mentions, your work shows something stronger, which is that if there is **any** $m$ such that $m+x=m$, then $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!